# How do I give a user shell access that requires a key

Tags: ssh, login, sshd, administration

This might be a stupid question, but what process should be taken to add a user to a system and provide them access when the system requires the use of a ssh keys?

For example on a system that doesn't require a key (password is acceptable), I can add the user, set a temporary password and require them to change it on their next login (which isn't a problem).

On a system that requires a key to access, and the user does not have a key-pair, what is the correct procedure for providing access to a person? From my understanding, a private key should never leave the system, if I generate them one, I would need to send them the key-pair so they could login which goes against the recommendation.

Is there a "upon first login, create a ssh-key pair" option? Or should I just make the user generate a key-pair and have them send me their public key?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a "upon first login, create a ssh-key pair" option? Or should
>   I just make the user generate a key-pair and have them send me their
>   public key?

If a password is required, how will they login the first time?

Given your constraints it sounds like you'll have to just have them send you a public key.  Depending on how skillful you expect users to be, you might want to provide them with a utility that can help generate this for them.  Otherwise, just have them run ssh-keygen and send you the id_rsa.pub file it generates.

Comment: Fair point. Wasn't thinking. That is the problem with most users, they are all on Windows and unfamiliar with generating key-pairs. Sounds like that is the option I'll have to go to.